# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Calculator project error)

Tags: c#

Ok, I'm pretty sure my code is all correct, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  :P  Here is my code -->

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());  //This is where I am getting the error at
        }
    }
}
```

That's in my program.cs file.  Here's what's in my Form1.cs file.  -->

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn0.Text;
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn1.Text;
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn2.Text;
        }

        private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn3.Text;
        }

        private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn4.Text;
        }

        private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn5.Text;
        }

        private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn6.Text;
        }

        private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn7.Text;
        }

        private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn8.Text;
        }

        private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Text += btn9.Text;
        }

        private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtbox.Text == "0")
            {
                txtbox.Text = "0.";
            }
            else
            {
                txtbox.Text += btnPoint.Text;
            }
        }

        private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add plus code here
        }

        private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add minus code here
        }

        private void btnTimes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add times code here
        }

        private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add divide code here
        }

        private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add equal code here
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtbox.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I attempt to enter in a number and then a decimal.  For example, I press "2" and then ".".  What happens is the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." pops up.  Help is appreciated, thanks.  Sorry if it's a stupid error.  :P

Comment: Attach the debugger. Inspect the variables/expression when the Exception occurs - which is `null`, and why? (The debugger is much better for debugging that SO in most cases and since VS/C# debugging is *really nice*, and *free*, use it.)

Comment: Post the StackTrace. Or just look at it yourself. It has the answers.

Comment: I type a number into the textbox, such as 2.  Then I try to enter the decimal, but it gives me an error, at the specified line.

Comment: Instead of txtbox.Text += btnPoint.Text; in your btnPoint_Click method, have your tried txtbox.Text += "."? If your not getting an error on pressing '0' and '.', this may help you identify the cause (something to do with retrieving that particular value).

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Several helpful ideas have been given to you in the comments to your question, so I will try to aggregate what is the most preferred analysis route here and add my own comments:

First, the line where the exception occur (`Application.Run(new Form1());`) is not the real place to look for the bug. Application.Run is a WinForm infrastructure method which does some magic and then runs your code.

Second, the best way to track down where the issue is is by setting a *breakpoint* in the btnPoint_Click method. I assume you are new to WinForm and Visual Studio, so my suggestion is searching for "Winform Debug" in youtube - there are many videos showing how to do exactly that. Basically the idea is clicking with the mouse on the left side of the line you want to break into (or one line below if it's a method declaration like in your case), and then, run your application from within Visual Studio by pressing F5. This will enable Visual Studio to automatically attach to your WinForm process, and let you see variables in runtime.
This will allow you to continue line by line (clicking F10) and navigating to the exact place in code where the exception occur.

Last, since this happens when clicking on the '.' button, the only two variables that can cause this type of exception are **txtbox** and **btnPoint**, and if one of them is null - that would be it.
If you hover with the mouse on the varibale name during debugging (following the instructions above), you should see whether the content of the variable is null or not (null will simply say 'null').